# Can't download the target file in vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

In the target manager I added a database.In the database I added an image and gave width 10.But when I am going to download the unity package ,it is not downloading .I tried so many times .Here is a screenshot which types of error I am gating.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyFd2.png)

Comment: Looks like an internet issue or a Vuforia server issue. Not much you can do but wait a little while

Comment: Okay I can confirm. I just got the same error and yesterday I was downloading data-sets. The answer is Vuforia marker DB is currently down, so no worries it will soon be up again.